# jquery validation not working for display none though i gave class name in the ignore

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

1. Currently working on the great jQuery validation form where I have
   two radio button, two drop down and one button initially when the
   user click safe and next button  the error message shows you have
   one field is missing  and the error class applied for the particular
   drop down
2. If the user select second radio button that is Post graduate still the error message will show you have one field missing because i have not selected the value in any of the drop down. If i selected the value Undern PG section of the drop down the error message should go the same should happen in UG also.

Here is my current jquery code where I have tried using class name in the ignore property

```
  $(".basicForm").validate({
   //ignore: "input[type='select']:hidden",

   ignore: "slt_mjrpg",
     onkeyup: false,
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();

        if (errors) {
            var message = errors === 0 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' : 'You have missed ' + errors + ' fields. Please fill the highlited field before submit.';
            $("#error_message").html(message);
            $(".error_msge").show();
        } else {
            $(".error_msge").hide();
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
   // errorClass: "errRed",
    errorPlacement: function () {
        return false;
    },
    highlight: function (element) {

        if ($(element).is(":hidden"))  {

        } else {
            $(element).addClass('errRed');
            $('#imageUploadForm').addClass('errRed');
            if($(element)[0].type=="file"){
               $("#upload_error").text('Please upload only jpeg').css("color","red");                             }
        }
        $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-red').removeClass('text-error-black');            
    },


    unhighlight: function (element) {

        if ($(element).is(':radio')) {
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass('errRed');
            //$('#imageUploadForm').closest('.choose_file').removeClass('errRed');
        }
        $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('text-error-red');

    },

    rules: {
        /*1*/sel_sem:"required",
        /*2*/txt_Fname: "required",
        /*3*/txt_Lname: "required",
        /*5*/txt_Mfname: "required",
        /*6*/txt_Mlname: "required",
        /*7*/txt_dob: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        },
        /*9*/sel_ms:"required",
        /*10*/sel_rg:"required",  
        /*11*/txt_Pptnum: "required",
        /*12*/country:"required",
        /*13*/txt_Emirat:"required",
        /*14*/txt_Pptnum: "required",
        /*15*/ipt_nation:"required",
        /*16*/txt_Pi:"required",
        /*17*/txt_Idt:"required",
        /*18*/txt_Epdt:"required",
        /*22*/ipt_city:"required",
        /*23*/txt_Emd: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        /*24*/sel_phntype:"required",
        /*25*/txt_CC:{
            required: true,
            number:true,
            maxlength:3
        },
        /*26*/txt_Pno:{
             required: true,
            number:true
        },
        /*27*/slt_mjr:"required",
        /*28*/slt_mjrpg:"required",//this validation will display only when pg radio button selected
        /*29*/slt_evt:"required"

    },

});
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/c0d1wde3/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The jQuery Validation Engine is not the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: sorry for that @Sparky can you please look this question

Comment: Due to poor grammar and a total lack of sentence structure, I cannot make any sense out of your question.  Please edit and insert appropriate punctuation, like a period at the end of each sentence.  Otherwise, we're just guessing about what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about how to use `ignore`.  The `ignore` option tells the plugin to "ignore" the element for validation.  In other words, if you set it to `input[type='text']:hidden`, then all `type='text'` elements that are also hidden will be ignored.

However, you set yours to `type='select'` and there is no such thing.

If you want to ignore a hidden `select` element, then set it to `select:hidden`

```
ignore: "select:hidden"
```

---

**EDIT:**

After reviewing the jsFiddle...

1. You do not need to use the `ignore` option since any/all hidden fields are already ignored by default.
2. You have a `value="0"` on the first `option` of your second `select` element.  In order for `required` validation to work, this **must** be set to `value=""`.

It's working now:  http://jsfiddle.net/c0d1wde3/2/

Comment: you mean to say i have to give select:hidden for the ignore is that possible can you please update fiddle it would be great help ful for me

Comment: @Mahadevan, I just gave you the answer.  Feel free to update your own jsFiddle.

Comment: the problem is even though if i gave input[type='text']:hidden the error count is not reducing please guide me

Comment: @Mahadevan, due to poor grammar and a total lack of sentence structure, I cannot make any sense out of your question.  However, I spotted code that makes no sense... there is no such element as `input[type="select"]`... so why would you change it to `type="text"` if you're trying to ignore `<select>` elements?

Comment: @hi sparky thanks for the reply initially when the user click safe & next button error message was showing you have one field missed and if the user select PG radio button and if you see still the error message saying you have one field missed but if the user select any of the value from the drop down under the  PG radio button the error should be none because the user select some value

Comment: @Mahadevan, until you construct a proper sentence, I cannot make any sense out of what you're typing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93008/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-sparky).

Comment: hi @Sparky can you please join in the chat discussion

Comment: is that possible once the user select  value from the drop down onfocusout the error should hide  for example if user click the value from undergraduate the error hide

Comment: @Mahadevan, that's already exactly how it's working!  The error message disappears when they select a value from the dropdown.